# Garry's Mod maximum amount of addons/mods

Tags: mods, garrys-mod

Is there a limit to the amount of addons/mods I can have installed in Garry's Mod?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the only limit is your computer's performance!

EDIT: As @Codingale pointed out in his answer, there is in fact a limit.

Comment: I think you didn't enough research at the time there was enough information and even an discussion that I've touched about in my answer. However not many people hit the limit, so it's understandable.

Comment: I said "As far as I know" because I used to play GMod 2 with tons of mods but I haven't encountered any issue. You seems right tho.

Comment: What do we do now? The current answer isn't correct and I doubt the original asker is around anymore.

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: ive found that (at least with me) if i install more than 100 addons onto a dedicated server it breaks the server and just makes everything seem very black and you spawn with nothing, it is not anything to do with my computer as my computer has plenty of extra memory when the game runs.  but again it could just be me

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is somewhat, not a limit of what content or anything however there is a limit on how many Lua files may be loaded at once.

https://github.com/Facepunch/garrysmod-issues/issues/1058#issuecomment-46835256

> The current limit seems to be 4096. I doubled it so it should now be 8192. If that didn't change anything let me know, maybe there's another hardcoded limit within the engine and it might be a bit more tricky to remove.

So you can have as many addons so long as the number of Lua files does not exceed 8192.